# Bind a VM to different views, depending on VM's properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Now I have the following code:

**ViewModel(s)**

```
public class VMBase
{
   public string TabID{get;set;}
   public string TabHeader {get;set;}
}

public class VM1:VMBase //implements the properties in base class
{
}

public class VM2:VMBase //implements the properties in base class
{
}
```

And in my `DataTemplate.xaml`, I have the different local controls binded to the `ViewModel`, depending on the type of `ViewModel` it is, ie:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:VM1}">
  <local: Control1 />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:VM2}">
  <local: Control2 />
</DataTemplate>
```

`Control1` and `Control2` are different types of `UserControl`:

```
public class Control1:UserControl
{
}

public class Control2:UserControl
{
}
```

Things are still manageable when I have only two derived classes for `VMBase`, but what if I have ten? Or more? It's going to get ugly.

**Is it possible to bind a single VM to different views ( user control)**, so that I don't have to manually create so many derived class for `VMBase`? I will just need to specify the VM properties such as `TabID` and `TabHeader`, correct views will be bind as a result.

Edit:

Here are further details: my VM is bind to a ContentControl (ie: `contentcontrol.Content=VM`). And each VM has two properties `TabID` and `Header`. Whether the `DataTemplateSelector` should be invoked depends on whether it has a specific `TabID` ( if it has other `TabID` then this DataTemplateSelector shouldn't be invoked), and which DataTemplate ( the logic inside the DataTemplateSelector ) to invoke depends further on the `Header`. How to implement this?

Comment: With Caliburn micro this is totally automatic and transparent. It uses a ViewLocator method somewhere. Consider using a MVVM framework or at least glean through their code.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, maybe you would like to show some examples on how Caliburn micro solves this problem?

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're trying to solve. Your question is too vague. If you are only displaying `TabID` and `TabHeader`, why do you need a different template for each model sub-class? If each model sub-class has additional properties you want to display, why not define a template for the base class and then incorporate that (via `ContentPresenter`) into your sub-class templates? Please provide enough context so your question is unambiguous, including a good [mcve] and a precise explanation of what's "ugly" about the code.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I just want to refactor the above code so that I don't have to define a dozens of subclass of VMBase. I need different template for each model sub-class because the view control is different

Comment: _" because the view control is different"_ -- in what way? please address the questions I actually asked.

Comment: The view control is different in the sense that they are different types of `UserControl`

Comment: Caliburn uses conventions, basically call them Item1ViewModel and Item1View and Caliburn will match them automatically. The ViewModels can use inheritance, for the Views that's useful but not required afaik.

Comment: Where are you supposed to do the mapping between a VM1 and Control1 if you don't define a DataTemplate...?

Comment: @mm8, can I somewhat automate this mapping by using code?

Comment: Why the downvote? SO has become very a nasty place recently

Comment: @Graviton: I don't see the point, you should define the views in XAML and do the mapping there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated answer - v2 (as per question edit)

I think simply returning a `null` in your `DataTemplateSelector` when `TabID` is not a match should do the trick, as WPF will then try and pick the next best match (i.e. the template that matches the `DataType`). In case the `TabID` is a match, you can return the template based on the `TabHeader` value.

So your custom `DataTemplateSelector` would look like this:

```
public class TabHeaderDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var element = container as FrameworkElement;
        if (element == null)
            return null;

        var viewModel = item as VMBase;
        if (viewModel == null || viewModel.TabID != "02") 
            return null; //continue only if TabID is a match

        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            switch(viewModel.TabHeader)
            {
                case "two":
                    return element.FindResource($"Template2") as DataTemplate;
                case "three":
                    return element.FindResource($"Template3") as DataTemplate;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

*Sample XAML*

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- data template for VM1 -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM1}">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Stroke="Black" />
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding TabHeader}" FontSize="18"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- data template for VM2 -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM2}">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Stroke="Red" />
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding TabHeader}" FontSize="18"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="4"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding TabHeader}" FontSize="24" 
                Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template3">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding TabHeader}" FontSize="24" 
                Foreground="White" Background="Black" FontWeight="Bold"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplateSelector">
            <Setter.Value>
                <local:TabHeaderDataTemplateSelector />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Margin="25">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding VmObj_1}" />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding VmObj_2}" />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding VmObj_3}" />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding VmObj_4}" />
</StackPanel>
```

*and the code-behind*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new
        {
            VmObj_1 = new VM1 { TabID = "01", TabHeader = "one" },
            VmObj_2 = new VM1 { TabID = "02", TabHeader = "two" },
            VmObj_3 = new VM2 { TabID = "02", TabHeader = "three" },
            VmObj_4 = new VM2 { TabID = "03", TabHeader = "four" },
        };
    }
}

public class VMBase
{
    public string TabID { get; set; }
    public string TabHeader { get; set; }
}

public class VM1 : VMBase { }

public class VM2 : VMBase { }
```

---

### Updated answer - v1

You can approach this problem in two different ways. Each option has its own set of pros and cons; but my most recommended approach would be (as @jon-stødle suggested) is to use a `DataTemplateSelector`

**Option 1** - Use DataTemplateSelector

As you are using `Type` based data-template(s) - then I assume you are most probably using a `ContentControl` (or a variant) to display the dynamic view-model driven UI. `ContentControl` and other templated controls such as `Label`, `UserControl`, `ItemsControl`, `ListBox` etc. usually have dependency property like `ContentTemplateSelector` or `ItemTemplateSelector` that you can bind your template-selector to.

You can refer [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) for an example for using `Label` with `DataTemplateSelector`; or following example for usage with `TabControl`

*XAML:*

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Tab1Template">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Stroke="Black" />
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding}" FontSize="18"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Tab2Template">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="4"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding}" FontSize="24" 
                        Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Tab3Template">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding}" FontSize="24" 
                        Foreground="White" Background="Black" FontWeight="Bold"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplateSelector">
            <Setter.Value>
                <local:TabIdDataTemplateSelector />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.ItemsSource>
        <col:ArrayList>
            <sys:String>1</sys:String>
            <sys:String>2</sys:String>
            <sys:String>3</sys:String>
        </col:ArrayList>
    </TabControl.ItemsSource>
</TabControl>
```

*DataTemplateSelector:*

```
public class TabIdDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var element = container as FrameworkElement;
        if (element == null)
            return null;

        //var vm = item as VMBase;
        //var id = vm.TabId;
        string id = item as string;
        if (id != null)
        {
            return element.FindResource($"Tab{id}Template") as DataTemplate;
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

**Option 2** - Use `Style` based data-triggers

Another option is use data-trigger(s) on the property (i.e. TabId) of your ViewModel to update the `ContentTemplate` of your container-view (i.e.  `TabControl`).

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Tab1Template">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Stroke="Black" />
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="18"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Tab2Template">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="4"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="24" 
                    Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Tab3Template">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="24" 
                    Foreground="White" Background="Black" FontWeight="Bold"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TabId}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Tab1Template}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TabId}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Tab2Template}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TabId}" Value="3">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Tab3Template}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<TabControl DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" 
            SelectedValue="{Binding TabId}">
    <TabControl.ItemsSource>
        <col:Hashtable>
            <sys:String x:Key="1">one</sys:String>
            <sys:String x:Key="2">two</sys:String>
            <sys:String x:Key="3">three</sys:String>
        </col:Hashtable>
    </TabControl.ItemsSource>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Your solution seems good,  but is it possible to bind the `Style` to a `ViewModel` ( in my case here, it's `VMBase`), instead of a View element ( in this case, it's `TabControl`)?

Comment: Just to better understand your question - which option are we talking about here? Because in option-3, the style works with DataContext properties only.

Comment: The style targettype is targeted to tabcontrol which is a view right ? But all my differentiating property, such as tabid, is tied to VM, not the tabcontrol per second

Comment: Updated answer with more clarification - removed the style-trigger option as it might not apply in your case.

Comment: Sorry for not making my question clearer: my VM is bind to a ContentControl (ie: `contentcontrol.Content=VM`). And each VM has two properties `TabID` and `Header`. Whether the `DataTemplateSelector` should be invoked depends on whether it has a specific `TabID`, and which DataTemplate to invoke depends further on the `Header`. How to implement this?

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly. The DataTemplateSelector will always be invoked, but will provide a template/view only when it matched specific TabID; on receiving `null` from selector WPF will revert to the next best match - i.e. data-type based template/view. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a `DataTemplateSelector`. It let's you choose a `DataTemplate` based on different criteria.

```
public class TaskListDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var element = container as FrameworkElement;
        var vmBase = item as VMBase;

        if (element != null && vmBase != null)
        {
            switch(vmBase.TabID)
            {
                case "Tab1": return element.FindResource("Tab1Template") as DataTemplate;
                case "Tab2": return element.FindResource("Tab2Template") as DataTemplate;
                default: return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about them in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=netframework-4.7) or have a look at [this](https://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html) tutorial.

Comment: After checking, I'm not too sure how it helps my problem here: on what objects I can bind `TaskListDataTemplateSelector` to ? There isn't any `ListBox` equivalent here

Comment: Assuming you're using WPF, a `ListView` should do the job. It also has the `ItemTemplateSelector` property